# Installing mysql.connector 2.1.3 on Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql

I downloaded the installer Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer Python 2.7 from 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python but got an error:

Python v2.7 not found. We only support Python installed using the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) downloaded from http://www.python.org/download.

I use Anaconda2. I am able to install mysql.connector from pip:

```
pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```

But it is not the most recent version (2.0.4 vs. 2.1.3). Any tips on how to install the new version on my Windows machine x64? Thank you.

Comment: My solution has been to install Python 2.7 from the standard distribution, install the new version of mysql.connector 2.1.3 and copy the following files to my Anaconda folder:

- Lib/site-packages/mysql folder
- Lib/site-packages/_mysql_connector.pyd
- Lib/site-packages/libmysql.dll
- Lib/site-packages/mysql_connector_python-2.1.3-py2.7.egg-info

And it works. Hope it will help.